# AS3/Air/Starling mobile app textinput class and how to get text value when in a class

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

I have a mobile app built in as3/air for mobile devices and I am wondering what the best approach to handle textinput fields are.

What I mean is I have multiple input fields on multiple screens. The inputs have a label (textfield), background color under the label (quad) and an input (textinput). Some are password, some are not. Some are different width/heights, multi-line/single line etc. All however use embedded fonts, have a name and ID assigned etc.

I have created a class file that extends Sprite and built all the components of the textinput (textfield, quad, textinput) so my other classes/screens can just create a new instance of this class passing custom values.

```
var textField:TextFieldClass = new TextFieldClass();
textField.DrawTextField(name, ID, width, height, isPassword, hasLabel, labelPosition etc);
```

The above works great. I can reuse the class to draw multiple textinput on screen with minimal code however I am having trouble getting the text value/ID/name when there are multiple instances.

I have tried adding each textField instance into an array and iterating through but that gets x number of the last textField instance e.g. if first instance is named txtEmail and the second is txtPassword, I get 2 txtPasswords.

I have also tried getChildByName and specifying the name of the textinput but when I use txtEmail I get a cannot access null value but txtPassword works.

Maybe I am going about this wrong so happy to use a better approach if one exists (which I am sure there is). Basically I would like to have a reusable textinput class that allows custom design (quads, fonts etc) without having to copy paste the entire textinput code for each new input field.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you made an error in your code adding the text fields to the array. Can you post that code?

Comment: did you try using feathers for text input?

Comment: Did you try using [gazman-sdk](http://gazman-sdk.com) for text inputs?